# Commit all folders and files in a directory using commandline

Tags: svn, command-line, cmd

We are having trouble with having a generalized approach to committing with a batch file using commandline SVN.

We've got a backup script that created a new folder with the current date containing the database dumps of our database. (Yes, we version control our database).

Now how can I use the `svn commit` command to `include all` directories that are new in the project?

Is there an approach without using the `svn add` command?`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`svn add --force .` will add all the files and directories below your current working directory that aren't added yet (and aren't ignored) to your working copy.

A `svn ci -m ""` will then handle the commit.

The only way without 'svn add' would be to use 'svn import', but this assumes a new location.

Comment: Here is a link to the relevant documentation:  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html

Comment: svn ci -m "Some message" for no svn complainings

Comment: Must it be current working dir? or can you specify a specific path?

Comment: You can just add a custom path. And (re: @PabloSGPacheco), there might be rules on the repository that add additional rules, such as 'no empty log message', but that is not the default config.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You must `svn add` files before you can commit them.

You could use wildcards, or have your script construct a list of what's to be added, which can then be passed to the `--targets` option.